How to write a user defined text inside the chart area
I am new to ChartJS so I am not sure about this live chart with text editor area to write user defined text functionality, which is available or not(see the below image for more detail).
Live chart with user annotation
If it is available please let me know how to do it?
FYI: After export to excel I need to see the value in the excel as well.
Thanks in Advance!
Running live chart in ChartJS with user defined text annotation functionality with export option is available?
If available please share me the sample how to do in ChartJS?

please provide a clear question on what needs to be fixed or happen and an code snippet of the code in question
